# How to have a general View element in Design

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using Constraint Layout.

I would like to have a general View element in my design, when I drag the "View" element [image] to my Design

Android studio pops up a long list asking me to select one:
[image]

This is confusing to me, I just need a general `View` element, that's it, I am not sure which one I should chose from the list because none of them is a general View. Could someone help me on how to have a general View element to my Design? (I know I can do it in xml file but I am wondering how to do in Design)

Comment: What happens, if you **type** `<View />`?

Comment: @ModularSynth, Like I mentioned in my question, I know how to add <View> in xml, I am just wondering how to do the same thing in Design, that's the whole point of my question here.

Comment: I thought you wanted a **fix**.